# Lagrange Multiplier with $3$ variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Here is the question:
$f(x,y,z) = x + 2y^2 - 3z$ subject to the constraint $z = 4x^2 + y^2$.

I don't understand how to do this because when I take the partial derivative in respect to $z$, I get $-3 = 0$, which doesn't make sense.

Can someone please help me? I don't need it all worked out, just what to do from here...

Comment: It says to maximize by the way

Comment: The constraint function is expressed as $ \ g(x,y,z) \ = \ 4x^2 + y^2 - z \ . $ From there, you would set up the "Lagrange equations" by way of $ \ \nabla f = \lambda \cdot \nabla g \ . $

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\max_{x,y,z}\quad &x+2y^2-3z\\
s.t. \quad 4x^2+y^2-z&=0\\
\therefore \mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda)&=x+2y^2-3z-\lambda\cdot(4x^2+y^2-z)\\
\nabla\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda)&=
\begin{pmatrix}1\\4y\\-3\end{pmatrix}-
\lambda\cdot\begin{pmatrix}8x\\2y\\-1\end{pmatrix}=0\\
\mbox{Now, From Equation (3):}\\
\implies-3+\lambda&=0\implies \lambda=3.\\
\mbox{Now, From Equation (1):}\\
\therefore 1-3\cdot8x&=0\implies x={1\over24}\\
\mbox{Now, From Equation (2):}\\
4y-3\cdot2y&=0\implies y=0\\
\mbox{Now, from the Equality Constraint:}\\
4x^2+y^2-z&=0\implies z={1\over144}\\
\mbox{Solution}&=\{{1\over24},0,{1\over144}\}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

f(x,y) = x + 2y^2 - 3(4x^2 + y^2) = -12x^2 + x - y^2. The function g(x) = -12x^2 + x is a parabola with vertex x = -b/2a = -1/(2(-12)) = 1/24. So max g = g(1/24) = 1/48 ==> max f = 1/48 at (x,y,z) = (1/24,0,1/144).

Comment: +1 Exactly the way I did it.  No need for multipliers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Let's $\ds{{\cal F} \equiv x + 2y^{2} - 3z - \mu\pars{z - 4x^{2} - y^{2}}}$

> $$
> \begin{array}{rclcrcrcl}
> 0 & = & \partiald{{\cal F}}{x} & \imp & 1 & + & 8\mu x & = & 0
> \\
> 0 & = & \partiald{{\cal F}}{y} & \imp & 4y & + & 2\mu y & = & 0
> \\
> 0 & = & \partiald{{\cal F}}{z} & \imp & -3 & - & \mu  & = & 0
> \end{array}
> $$

Then, $\mu = -3$
$$
\imp\quad x = -\,{1 \over 8\mu} = {1 \over 24}\,,\quad y = 0
$$